# Iterating over Hours for 1 month in Ruby takes 15 seconds - What's the best way to iterate over intervals of time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

If I iterate over 1 month of time to do something for each hour, it takes about 14 seconds using `Range#step`:

```
bm = Benchmark.measure do
  (Time.now..(Time.now + 1.month)).step(1.hour) { |hour| puts hour.inspect }
end
puts bm
=> 14.750000   0.060000  14.810000 ( 14.907838)
```

That's because it's iterating over every [second]?  What is the best way to create and iterate over a range of times for each hour, from the beginning of the hour?

```
range == [...Wed Feb 09 11:00:00 -0600 2011, Wed Feb 09 12:00:00 -0600 2011, ...]
```

Comment: I think you can't use `step` this way in Ruby 1.9.2. Here at least, it throws `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be an alternative. Seems to be a lot quicker at least.

```
bm = Benchmark.measure do
  time = Time.now
  while time < (Time.now + 1.month)
    puts time.inspect
    time += 1.hour
  end
end
puts bm
=> 0.483000   0.000000   0.483000 (  0.546000)
```

Comment: `1.hour` is not standard Ruby. It usually requires Rails' ActiveSupport so you might want to show how to correctly require that as it's not straight-forward in Rails 3+

Comment: Good point, but since it was actually used in the question I figured it might not be necessary to explain.

Comment: Good point. I'll add Rails to the tags for the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

```
t = Time.now
0.upto(1.month/1.hour) {|i| puts t+i*1.hour}
```

Note: assumes you have required `activesupport` for the `1.month` and `1.hour`. Also this gives you constant sized months (2592000 seconds), which rather limits its usefulness.

Comment: This is the most idiomatic approach, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well a month of time is not a constant.  You also have to deal with daylight savings time etc.  So to iterate over a month (or any time span) by hour quickly and more accurately:

```
bm = Benchmark.measure do
  s_time = Time.local(2011,1,1)
  e_time = Time.local(2011,2,1)
  while(s_time < e_time)
    puts s_time.inspect
    s_time += 3600
  end
end

puts bm

0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.010531)
```

If you want to only display hours on top of hour between arbitrary times:

```
 s_time += s_time.to_i % 3600
 e_time -= e_time.to_i % 3600
```

Comment: `Time.parse` doesn't work the way you think it does. `Time.parse('2/1/2011') #=> 2011-01-02 00:00:00 -0700`, which is Jan. 2, not Feb. 1. `parse` doesn't know about how we normally do MM/DD/YYYY in America. Instead if uses DD/MM/YYYY, which is the standard for Europe. The fallout of this is that your benchmark's time is a lot less than it should be, because you didn't iterate over the right number of hours.

Comment: This iterated over all hours for me because I am using ruby 1.8.7.  What you say is true about ruby 1.9 it has changed. Example changed to account work with Ruby 1.9 as well as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I wrote to iterate over days in rails.

```
def each_day(range, &block)
  values = []
  (range.first.to_i .. range.last.to_i).step(1.day) { |d| values << Time.at(d) }
  return values unless block_given?
  values.each { |val| yield(val) }
end

range = (Time.local(2012, 12, 31) .. Time.local(2013, 1, 1))

each_day(range) { |d| puts d.inspect }
```